# PyPNG fails to make image with 32-bit array input

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image

starting with ML and wrote an Classifier.

Now i want to convert 2D arrays back to an image if the classifier gives out an false value.

I use PyPNG and i am getting errors.

```
png.from_array(img.reshape((32, 32, 3), order='F').swapaxes(0,1), 
mode='RGB').save(falseFolderPath + file)

ValueError: bitdepth (32) must be a positive integer <= 16
```

So how do i give it a bitdepth to work with?

Edit: 
The image is feeded and converted like this:

```
img = scipy.ndimage.imread(imagePath, mode="RGB")

img = scipy.misc.imresize(img, (32, 32), interp="bicubic").astype(np.float32, 
casting='unsafe')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: By being careful with the types within img, e.g. uint32 vs. uint8. I probably would also switch to something more common, like imageio.

Comment: Please go through some basics of image-formats. Then it's easy to see that `np.float32` and `bitdepth (32) must be a positive integer <= 16` is a problem. Make sure to understand the issues of uint vs. float-based storage (e.g. png is solely uint-based) and be careful with typecasts. Sure, even a gaussian-filter will need and produce continuous/float output, but png-output will need unsigned integers again. Some libs like skimage might help.